# FluentValidation: How to reference property of parent object when validating a collection

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Would like to display the Id of the Order for any error that occurs when validating the Item collection.  The model being validated is way more complex than shown here, but I simplified it to just the root issue.  We would like the API to help the client identify the Order Id that has errors associated with it.

One way of doing this is to "pass" the parent object Id down using Root Context Data, but that is only accessible in the Item validator using a Custom rule... what I don't like about this is I can't use the built-in validators with consistent error messages.  Here's the code I tried that doesn't work:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
}

public class OrderValidator : AbstractValidator<Order>
{
    protected override bool PreValidate(ValidationContext<Order> context, ValidationResult result)
    {
        if (context.InstanceToValidate == null)
        {
            result.Errors.Add(new ValidationFailure("", "Please ensure a model was supplied."));
            return false;
        }

        context.RootContextData["ParentId"] = context.InstanceToValidate.OrderId;

        return true;
    }

    public OrderValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(x => x.Items).SetValidator(new ItemValidator());
    }
}

public class ItemValidator : AbstractValidator<Item>
{
    public ItemValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ItemDescription).Custom((item, context) =>
        {
            var parentId = int.Parse(context.RootContextData["ParentId"].ToString());

            // Can't do RuleFor in custom, gives:
            // System.InvalidOperationException
            // Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
            RuleFor(item => item.ItemDescription).NotNull();
        });
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, that code throws an exception.  Does anyone have any suggestions to accomplish what I'm trying to do, leveraging the built-in validators?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, so you want to customize error message when `ItemDescription` is null, it should show the error message contains the `parentId` value?

Comment: Yes, I want to include the parent Id in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to override the `Validate` method on the `ItemValidator` and adjust any error messages before returning them.

That `Validate` method has access to the `ValidationContext` in order to retrieve the `OrderId`.

```csharp
public class ItemValidator : AbstractValidator<Item>
{
    public ItemValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(item => item.ItemDescription).NotNull();
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<Item> context)
    {
        var validationResult = base.Validate(context);

        var orderId = context.RootContextData["ParentId"];

        foreach (var error in validationResult.Errors) 
        { 
            error.ErrorMessage = $"{error.ErrorMessage} (OrderId {orderId})";
        }

        return validationResult;
    }
}
```